# stacked colomn chart datetime type has lot of dates on xAxis

Tags: highcharts

When using a stacked colomn chart and xAxis type is datetime on the yAxis a lot of dates, although dispatched only 2 dates.

http://jsfiddle.net/jBxbe/

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
        },
        yAxis: {
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                stacking: 'normal',
                minPointLength: 3
            }
        },
            series: [{
            name: 'Ex1',
            data: [[1367280000000,8],[1369872000000,26349]]
        }, {
            name: 'Ex2',
            data: [[1367280000000,19196],[1369872000000,31213]]
        },]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

With such a minimal amount about data, you are probably better off using a `category` xaxis instead of datetime.  This will give you better control on the display.

```
 $(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Apr 2013','May 2013']                
        },
        yAxis: {
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                stacking: 'normal',
                minPointLength: 3
            }
        },
            series: [{
            name: 'Ex1',
            data: [8,26349]
        }, {
            name: 'Ex2',
            data: [19196,31213]
        },]
    });
});
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jBxbe/1/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use pointRange parameter http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.column.pointRange / tickInterval (http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.tickInterval) two categories http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.categories

Comment: Can you tell what minRange value will accomplish what the OP is looking for? I tried changing this value in the fiddle, but couldn't get it to work.

Comment: My mistake, it should be pointRange http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.column.pointRange